# R dbplyr WHERE clause cp1250 charset

Tags: mysql, r, character-encoding, dplyr, dbplyr

So my R uses cp1250 charset, `sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Czech_Czech Republic.1250  LC_CTYPE=Czech_Czech Republic.1250    LC_MONETARY=Czech_Czech Republic.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          LC_TIME=Czech_Czech Republic.1250
```

Now I want to work with MySQL database using `dbplyr` package. At first, when I connect to DB, I send the following mysql query:

```
SET NAMES 'cp1250';
```

Then when I send SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT dg_group
FROM transpl
WHERE `dg_group` = 'Hodgkinův lymfom'
```

it returns me 0 rows. BUT! When I set character encoding of string `'Hodgkinův lymfom'` to UTF-8, it returns me all the relevant rows. I set character encoding to UTF-8 like this:

```
x <- 'Hodgkinův lymfom'
Encoding(x) <- 'UTF-8'
```

Then the SELECT statement looks like this when I place variable `x` into the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT dg_group
FROM transpl
WHERE `dg_group` = 'Hodgkin<f9>v lymfom'
```

Although the transactions' encoding is cp1250, it is working with UTF-8 but not with cp1250.

By the way, when I make the following SELECT statement with `SET NAMES 'cp1250'`, returned values in the rows are correctly displayed:

```
SELECT *
FROM transpl
```

Any idea on what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These charsets treat hex `F9` as `ů`:  cp1250, cp1256, dec8, latin1, latin2, latin5.  For utf8/utf8mb4, it is hex `C3B9`

`SET NAMES` announces the charset of the *client*.

But what about the charset of the column you are storing into?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to find out.

When doing `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` do you get `F9` or `C3B9`?

More discussion: [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: At that time when I was writing my question, I did not really understand what is going on and why the described situation occurred instead of the "expected" one. I did not deal with understanding this thing at that time anymore. However, as I went through different experience in this field, I came across my question again and now I understand what is going on and so I marked your answer as the correct one. Thank you.